# java javap and groovy bytecode comparison

Tags: java, groovy, bytecode, javap, groovy-console

Here is the code generated showed by `javap` when I asked him to display my compiled class (I selected method)

```
int multiply(int, int);
  flags:
  Code:
    stack=2, locals=3, args_size=3
       0: iload_1
       1: iload_2
       2: imul
       3: ireturn
    LineNumberTable:
      line 2: 0
    LocalVariableTable:
      Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
             0       4     0  this   LMyClass;
             0       4     1     a   I
             0       4     2     b   I
```

Here is the code, which displayed by `groovyConsole`(same method)

```
public multiply(II)I
   L0
    LINENUMBER 4 L0
    ILOAD 1
    ILOAD 2
    IMUL
    IRETURN
   L1
    LDC 0
    IRETURN
    LOCALVARIABLE this LMyClass; L0 L1 0
    LOCALVARIABLE a I L0 L1 1
    LOCALVARIABLE b I L0 L1 2
    MAXSTACK = 2
    MAXLOCALS = 3
```

But which bytecode are more `raw`? As far as I understand, `javap` added some style to it, so the second example should be more genuine `bytecode`.
Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither of these is more raw. There are just two different ways of presenting exactly the same information.

Comment: I am curious which of them are more precise in display it the same way as in `class` file and judging by all the assemblers it is the second variant.

Comment: The .class file contains binary data. Because of this, neither of these representations shows the data in the same way as it is stored in the class file.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both Javap and Groovy do some amount of sugaring, but in different ways, so you can't really say that one is more "Raw" than the other. For example, Groovy displays the raw method descriptor `(II)I` which Javap sugars, while Javap displays the stack and locals counts and Groovy doesn't.

That being said, neither is particularly "raw". Javap is designed to help with Java debugging, so there a number of things that it tries to hide or rewrite in order to make the output more Java like. It isn't designed to handle unusual or maliciously constructed classfiles at all.

If you want the most "raw" disassembly output, your best choice is the [Krakatau disassembler](https://github.com/Storyyeller/Krakatau). Krakatau is the only disassembler which can represent every little detail in an arbitrary classfile, including non-java and maliciously constructed classfiles.